# Facing issue to upload build on live server

Tags: node.js, angular, live, production

I have upload my angular production build on live. And I'm missing some thing but I don't know what is that.

In `build/index.html` I have set this in base URL.

```
<base href="http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/">  // Instead of 0.0.0.0 I have set my EC2 instance's elastic ip address
```

I have set `/var/www/html/myapp/admin`. Hear in admin folder angular build is that.

And my node server is at `/var/www/html/app.js`

**app.js**

To allow all admin panel pages I have add this code in my app.js file.

```
app.use('/', express.static('./admin'))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendfile('./admin/index.html')
})
```

[image: Server image]

[image: Admin panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `app.use('/', express.static('./admin'))`, the static files will be served in the root directory, for example, http://0.0.0.0:3000/main.js, but because of the `base` tag, it will try to find the resource at http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/main.js.

To fix it, change the path of the static files, like so:

```
app.use('/admin', express.static('./admin'));
```

Also, I don't recommend editing the `base` tag manually, you can set the base url in the build command, like so:

```
ng build --prod --base-href="http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/"
```